# scala Tuple list, find each Key max value, not use groupBy

Tags: scala, group-by, aggregate

here is the code,

```
 val arr = List(("A", 1), ("B", 2), ("A", 3), ("B", 1), ("A", 2), ("C", 4), ("B", 5), ("C", 2))
 val res = arr.groupBy(x => x._1).map(x => x._2.maxBy(e => e._2))
```

get result like:

```
Map(A -> 3, C -> 4, B -> 5)
```

but `groupby` operator in large tuple list is very slow， i want use other operator, such as `foldleft` to achieve same result, unfortunately, i can not achieve such purpose.

in my question `scala` version is `2.10.5`

last share `groupby source code`

```
def groupBy[K](f: A => K): immutable.Map[K, Repr] = {
    val m = mutable.Map.empty[K, Builder[A, Repr]]
    for (elem <- this) {
      val key = f(elem)
      val bldr = m.getOrElseUpdate(key, newBuilder)
      bldr += elem
    }
    val b = immutable.Map.newBuilder[K, Repr]
    for ((k, v) <- m)
      b += ((k, v.result))

    b.result
  }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: `groupby` operator in large tuple list is very slow， i want use other operator, such as foldleft, Unfortunately， i can not achieve such purpose

Comment: If you are on `2.13` use `groupMapReduce` which will give you the answer in one iteration. If not you can write your own tail-recursive algorithm.

Comment: thks, in my question not declare my `scala` version (i use 2.10.5)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to iterate the list once:

```
val arr = List(("A", 1), ("B", 2), ("A", 3), ("B", 1), ("A", 2), ("C", 4), ("B", 5), ("C", 2))

val res: mutable.Map[String, Int] = arr.foldLeft(Map.empty[String, Int]) {
  case (acc, (key, value)) =>
    acc.get(key).fold(acc + (key -> value)) { oldValue =>
      acc + (key -> math.max(value, oldValue))
    }
}
```

If you don't want the allocation costs of the immutable `Map[String, Int], you can use a mutable one instead:

```
val res: Map[String, Int] = arr.foldLeft(mutable.Map.empty[String, Int]) {
  case (acc, (key, value)) =>
    acc.get(key).fold(acc += (key -> value)) { oldValue =>
      acc += (key -> math.max(value, oldValue))
    }
}
```

Comment: this get a empty Map

Comment: @BranY Yup, fixed the bug.

Comment: here map is very expensive, see this http://www.lihaoyi.com/post/BenchmarkingScalaCollections.html

Comment: @BranY If critical, you can use a `mutable.Map` instead to avoid allocations.

Answer (score 0):

```
arr.foldLeft(collection.mutable.Map.empty[String, Int]) {
  case (map, (k, v)) =>
    map.get(k) match {
      case Some(a) => map(k) = math.max(v, a)
      case _ => map(k) = v
    }
    map
}
```

**Note:** Use `mutable.Map` as you mentioned collection size is large.